# Prove by induction involving calculus

Tags: calculus, induction

Prove by induction.

Let $$f(x)={ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }$$
Then for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a polynomial ${ P }_{ n }(x)$ of degree $n$ such that
$$\frac { { d }^{ n } }{ { dx }^{ n } } f(x)={ P }_{ n }(x){ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }$$

Have tried the base case:
When $n=1$,$$\frac { d }{ dx } f(x)=2x{ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }$$
When $n=2$,$$f''(x)=(2x{ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } })'=4{ x }^{ 2 }{ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }$$

Comment: It's an induction - try the base case first. If you're still stuck, have a go at proving the next few cases to see if that gives you a hint.

Comment: @Peter no it is ${ e }^{ { 2 }^{ x } }$

Comment: Then what about the first derivate ? I don't get the desired form.

Comment: The first derivate of $f(x)$ is $f’(x)=e^{2^x}2^x\ln(2)$, but $2^x\ln(2)$ is NOT a polynomial. Something is wrong in your question.

Comment: Oppps. Sorry typo. $f(x)={ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }$. Edited the question.

Comment: @tooooony Hint : The product rule gives two summands which are of the form $P(x)\cdot e^{x^2}$, what remains is to show that the degree always increases by $1$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you checked the base case (n=1)?  Then assume it is true for $k$ and compute the $k+1$st derivative.  It should be easy to see that it is a polynomial times $e^{x^2}$ as desired.  You have to justify the degree.

Comment: $$\frac { { d }^{ n+1 } }{ { dx }^{ n+1 } } f(x)=\left[  { P' }_{ n }(x)+2xP_n(x)      \right]{ e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } } 
$$

Comment: What do you know about derivatives of polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very easy to "see" the inductive step. The tedious part is writing it out rigorously.

In the inductive step, assume the proposition is true for some $n=k$, i.e. $f^{(k)} = P_k(x)e^{x^2}$.

Then by product and chain rules, $f^{(k+1)} = P'_k(x)e^{x^2} + 2xe^{x^2}P_k(x) = e^{x^2}(P'_k(x) + 2xP_k(x))$

Represent $P_k(x) = a_0x^k + a_1x^{k-1} + ... + a_k = \sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^{k-i}$, where $a_0 \neq 0$ (lead coefficient non zero).

Then $P'_k(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)a_ix^{k-i-1}$. The final (constant) term in the summation vanishes, but the summation can still remain indexed this way.

Also, $2xP_k(x) = 2\sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^{k-i+1}$

Hence $P'_k(x) + 2xP_k(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)a_ix^{k-i-1} + 2\sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^{k-i+1} \\= \sum_{i=0}^k (2a_ix^{k-i+1} + (k-i)a_ix^{k-i-1})$

You can now observe that the summation is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ as the lead coefficient $a_0$ does not vanish and the power of the $x$ term of the lead term is $k+1$ (when $i=0$). Define $P_{k+1}(x) =  P'_k(x) + 2xP_k(x)$. You now have an explicit transformation from $P_k(x)$ to $P_{k+1}(x)$, as you've shown that $P'_k(x) + 2xP_k(x)$ always gives a polynomial of degree $k+1$ . This completes the inductive step. After the base case is shown, you're done.